# How to configure the ApiResource annotation

Tags: api-platform.com

I have added this annotation to one of my entities as I see in the last version of the docs with annotations instead of attributes (https://api-platform.com/docs/v2.5/core/serialization/):

```
 * @ApiResource(attributes={
 *     "normalization_context"={"enable_max_depth"=true}}
 * )
```

And I get this error:

```
An error occurred while instantiating the annotation @ApiResource declared on class App\Entity\Client: &quot;Argument 1 passed to ApiPlatform\Metadata\ApiResource::__construct() must be of the type string or null, array given
```

I'm using API Platform 2.7 because I'm still on PHP 7.4.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind... I had imported `\ApiPlatform\Metadata\ApiResource` instead of `\ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource`.